# Free Chrome extension for RSS feed notifications with cloud sync

Tags: gratis, chrome, rss

I'm looking for a chrome extension, that does the following:

- Searches pages for RSS links and gives you a button to subscribe (so that I don't have to look for them) (I don't want to copy-paste links to other pages)
- Displays that you have unread RSS feeds (number would be welcome)
- Syncs your subscribed feeds and what you've read across computers (while logged in with an account)
- Preferably has some presence on android / is accessible somehow (an app or a webpage)
- Is gratis

I've found [RSS Feed Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp?hl=en) but it's not free if you want to sync between devices.